# Order of two prepositional phrases

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, british-english

Which of these would be better:

> I came here from England for my education

or:

> I came here for my education from England

Comment: Why would either be wrong? You tell us. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of these is wrong, and the obviously intended meaning is the same. To me as a native speaker of US-English

> I came here from England for my education

seems much more natural. The other sentence:

> I came here for my education from England

tempts a reader to parse "my education from England" is if the education somehow came from England. A moment's thought shows this is not the intended meaning, but I think it contributes to the awkward feeling of this version.

Also, keeping the phrase  "I came here from England" together as a unit simplifies the sentence and makes it feel more natural, and I think that inserting a modifier within this phrase should only be done if there is some compensating benefit, which there is not in this case.